# Como Automatizar Interação em Janelas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

Gostaria de manipular uma janela utilizando o Python

O passo que eu gostaria de fazer é o seguinte:

1. Abrir o programa que está no Windows 10
2. Clica em um radio button da janela
3. Preencher um campo
4. Dar enter

O código que estou tentando fazer é esse:

```
import pyautogui
import os
import time

programa = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Software\Programa.exe'
os.system('"' + programa + '"')

time.sleep(10)
pyautogui.write('meu texto')
pyautogui.click(1258,263)
```

Mas nada acontece

Ai eu pensei que pudesse em relação a janela que abre e focar na janela, então adicionei o seguinte:

```
import pyautogui
import os
import time
import pygetwindow

programa = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Software\Programa.exe'
os.system('"' + programa + '"')

time.sleep(10)
window = pygetwindow.getWindowswithTitle(title)[0]
window.activate()
pyautogui.write('meu texto')
pyautogui.click(1258,263)
```

O script só continua quando fecho a janela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que pude ver em seu código existem 3 problemas, fazendo as correções será possível executar o seu script.

Primeira coisa é o nome de um método utilizado está errado:

```
window = pygetwindow.getWindowswithTitle(title)[0]
```

Que deveria ser substituída por:

```
window = pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle(title)[0]
```

Repare que aqui a letra `"w"` deve ser escrita em maiúsculo.

Outra mudança necessária é a maneira que fez a chamada para iniciar o programa, desta forma:

```
os.system('"' + programa + '"')
```

O sistema fica aguardando a saída da execução do programa que passou como parâmetro. E só vai continuar a execução do seu código após o programa ser fechado. No momento que o programa está aberto ele não possui nenhum valor de retorno, somente após ele terminar de executar (finalizado com sucesso com `exit code == 0` e finalizado com erro `exit code != 0`, esses valores de retorno tem relação com a execução de processos em um sistema operacional). Como esta é uma operação síncrona o seu script fica esperando este retorno, antes de poder continuar.

Dito isto uma maneira de fazer o seu programa funcionar é modificar esta linha para adicionar o `start` ao inicio da string. Ficando desta forma:

```
os.system('start "" "' + programa + '"')
```

Ou utilizar outro método para iniciar o programa, como por exemplo utilizar o módulo [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) ou o [`os.startfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os%20startfile#os.startfile) que vai iniciar um arquivo com uma aplicação associada àquele arquivo.

Fazendo desta forma então será possível executar o seu programa, segue um exemplo:

```
import pyautogui
import os
import time
import pygetwindow

programa = r'C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe'
os.system('start "" "' + programa + '"')
#ou usar 
#os.startfile(programa)
directory_path = os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE'],'Documents')
time.sleep(5)

window = pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle('Untitled')[0]
window.activate()
pyautogui.write('meu texto')
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 's')

pyautogui.write('{}\{}'.format(directory_path,'oi.txt'))
pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 's')
```

Agora deve haver um arquivo `oi.txt` salvo em: `C:\Users\<usuário>\Documents`

Neste caso a pasta `<usuário>` é dependente do usuário logado e é diferente para cada pessoa que está logada no sistema operacional (isso já é tratado no script), outra coisa é que da maneira que foi escrito este script só vai funcionar em sistemas operacionais Windows. Pois o programa `notepad` (que está localizado naquele diretório) só existe no Windows.

Este programa vai fazer os seguintes passos:

1. Abrir o notepad e aguardar 5s
2. Pegar a primeira janela que possui o título "Untitled"
3. Digitar o texto: `"meu texto"` no Notepad.
4. Salvar o arquivo `oi.txt` no diretório `"C:\Users\<usuário>\Documents"`

Segue a documentação de apoio necessária para interagir com as libs [`pygetwindow`](https://pypi.org/project/PyGetWindow/) e [`pyautogui`](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Olá, @Danizavtz! Agradeço sua resposta! Deu certo mas com algumas edições que precisei fazer que foi: Removi o `pygetwindow` pois o `windows .active()` estava dando erro. Então as duas linhas referentes ao pygetwindow não precisaram. Fora isso, sua resposta resolveu minha dúvida.. Obrigado

Comment: @CarlosBrito, beleza, engraçado no meu não deu erro, estou usando o python3.9.1. e as ultimas versões das libs. Resumindo, da maneira que está representado neste código é a mesma maneira que funcionou em minha máquina. Obrigado.